# What time(compile / runtime) a dependent node modules gets linked to the project when it is require()'ed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js. I just want to know when the dependent components actually gets linked with the js file which requires it, in the node.js environment.

My previous understanding in java is each dependent components(mostly *.jar libraries) will get linked to the project at run time. what would be the case when it is node.js ?

It would be helpful shed some light on compilation/execution process happening in node.js projects.

Thanks

Comment: JavaScript is not a compiled language. Also, it is different from Java.

Comment: @Vld: I think it depends on the browser engine no? For example Chrome's v8 engine does compile the javascript code for performing faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) on how modules work might give a bit more clarity. [This article](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/) delves into the source code and does a brief analysis on the functionality therein.

In a sense, there isn't really "linking" or "compiling" in the Java or C style.